# Receive unplugging of headphones takes too long

Tags: java, android, broadcast, headset

I want to pause the MediaPlayer when the user unplugs his headphones. I found out that I can use the `"ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY"` broadcast , so I tried it out !

Theoretically it works , BUT the time of receiving takes too long. The music is still playing for 3-5 seconds before it really pauses.This wouldnt be acceptable for an user.

How are other devolopers able to pause it in milliseconds ? Are there better Soloutions ?

My BroadcastReceiver which is actually for Notifications :

```
public class NotificationBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

...

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equals(android.media.AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY)) {

        Intent iPause = new Intent(context , SongService.class);
        iPause.putExtra("com.Hohos.mplay.Services.SongService.MEDIA_ACTION", NOTIFY_EXTRA_PAUSE);
        context.startService(iPause);
    }

...
}
```

I also added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG"/>`
, which really didnt any difference

Thanks for your help guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know when the user unplugs his headphones you need to listen the action [ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG) and check the `state` extra:

> Broadcast Action: Wired Headset plugged in or unplugged.
>
> The intent will have the following extra values:
>
> - state - 0 for unplugged, 1 for plugged.
> - name - Headset type, human
>     readable string
> - microphone - 1 if headset has a microphone, 0
>     otherwise

This is an example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private HeadsetBroadcastReceiver mHeadsetBroadcastReceiver;

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myReceiver = new HeadsetBroadcastReceiver();
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onResume() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
        registerReceiver(mHeadsetBroadcastReceiver, filter);
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(mHeadsetBroadcastReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }

    private class HeadsetBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override 
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {
                int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);

                if (state == 0) {
                    //Headset is unplugged
                } else if(state == 1) {
                    //Headset is plugged
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help , BUT somehow I dont get a broadcast . I used   "<action android:name="android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG"/>" in my intentfilter of the Receiver and used the permission "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG"/>" . Why can't I get a Broadcast ? (I also debugged to check it)

Comment: Ok I found out that I HAVE to register it dynamically. So this cant be done by registering it by manifest. Thank you Mattia !